# Bytebuddy match subtype by name

Tags: java, byte-buddy

How can I use AgentBuilder to match subclass with name?

I can easily match types itself

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .type(named("SomeClass"))
```

However there is no such thing as match for subtype by name:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .type(isSubtypeOf(named("SomeClass")))
```

Is it possible to match subtype by name?

Answer (score 2):

There is a matcher for this:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .type(hasSuperType(named("SomeClass")))
```

Matching `isSubtypeOf(SomeClass.class)` would however be more efficient, if the type is in the scope of the agent.